# How to select from table all names that started on any letter - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-like

How to select from table all names that contains any letter?
For example if variable is 'BANANA' it is great, if variable is '*895-+59' it is not great

```
IF variable LIKE '%A-Z%' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('GREAT');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to select from table all names that contains any letter?

You cannot use regular expressions in a `LIKE` comparison but you can use them in `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[A-Za-z]')
```

If you want the column to start with a letter then anchor it to the start of the string:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   table_name
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(name, '^[A-Za-z]')
```

If you want to output `Great` or `Not Great` then put it in a `CASE` expression rather than a `WHERE` filter:

```sql
SELECT name,
       CASE 
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[A-Za-z]')
       THEN 'Great'
       ELSE 'Not Great'
       END AS is_great
FROM   table_name
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand everything :D

Comment: Could you tell me also what shoud be in brackets if I want to take only names which start on letter A and G?

Comment: @MASTERSIPL Just A and G `'^[AG]'` (or `'^[AGag]'` if you also want lower case). But you could also use `name LIKE 'A%' or name LIKE 'G%'` rather than regular expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function with conditional such as

```sql
SELECT DECODE(SIGN(LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR('<your_expression>','[a-zA-Z]'))),1,'Great','Bad')
  FROM your_table
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5fd6419e35a368d2ddb4fba1277cc067)</kbd>